# How to deal with drop-down tabs dynamics crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In CRM 2011 I've a tab (drop-down), which has an Iframe or whatever.

Could i make it open by default if there is something inside and close by default if there isn't any data inside of this tab?.

Or, what if it's not an IFrame inside of tab, may be a web- resource

So, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want expand or collapse a tab in Onload of form, right?

So you have to use this function:

```js
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tabname").setDisplayState('expanded');
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tabname").setDisplayState('collapsed');
```

The state of the tab is independently of the content.

Comment: however, is it possible to do that the tab will be dependent of the content!? I mean, it the content is in a tab then the tab'll be "expanded" and if it isn't the the tab will be "collapsed"

Comment: Which content are you talking about? It's different accessing inside an Iframe or a control of crm form. But it's possible.

Comment: by content I mean, attached files for example

Comment: You want see the content of a attached file? This i think you can't. You can depend of a field in CRM Form or a field in a IFrame

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty common question. Dynamics CRM was designed this way for a few reasons. First, this better supports a company that has contacts and accounts in various countries around the world. Second, the integration with Outlook requires the field to be a single line of text for the field to sync with Outlook contacts. This means there are drawbacks to changing the state/province field to a pick list or lookup and must weigh your options carefully. Here are my recommendations if you add this field.

Comment: This answer appears to have submitted before you made your recommendations.  In it's current form it appears to be primarily commentary.